# How to assess neural network for effectiveness before fully commiting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

As a student who does some coding as a hobby, I have very limited computational power at my disposal. This becomes especially problematic when I try to build and train a neural network.

It takes hours if not days to train a decently powerful network on a modest computer. If I want to compare two different architectures for effectiveness, I will have to wait a substantial amount of time before I can test out either one.

For example, lets say I want to build  generative neural network for making music, and I want to determine whether to use an LSTM or casual convolutions. The time it takes either network to generate meaningful results (not random notes) would be 8+ hours. I would have to wait 16 hours to test out both architectures, and then be able to move on towards a final design.

While the obvious answer would be to get better hardware, the question would still remain relevant as the size of training data and model complexity increases.

The question is:

> Is their a heuristic for making a quick judgement on the future effectiveness of a neural network without fully committing to its training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into something called Curriculum Learning for your situation. Below is the original paper on the topic (you can find it outside a paywall with a google search if necessary).

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.149.4701

This approach provided a method for most efficiently ordering your data such that you learn most quickly. While there's no silver bullet for identifying if a particular model is going to perform well or not, if you apply Curriculum Learning you should at least speed up the learning process and pick up the largest percentage of your gains early on in the process.

I might also note that the proper application of Batch Normalization has shown significant improvements in convergence rate.

Comment: Hi could you further elaborate on proper vs inproper application of Batch Normalization?

Comment: The only improper use I've identified so far is getting the batch size wrong. There seems to be an optimal batch size. Too small and the batches don't contain enough variance and it learns slowly, but too large hurt accuracy in some recent tests I did. I'm sure there's more to know that I haven't yet stumbled upon.

Answer (score 3):

I work on nets quite a bit these days, and the sad answer is that there isn't a general rule of thumb. Just gotta let 'em rip.

You have two options though to speed up your test cycles:

1) Benchmark your architectures on small datasets. Compute some statistics about the network's performance after a short training cycle, and then test the effect of network changes on those stats (again on the small dataset). This may be difficult for a generative net for music though, as I'm not sure what stats would be indicative of better performance.

2) You're a student, which probably means you can get access to resources. When I was an undergrad, I got a few hundred dollars of AWS credits through school and used them to train networks on EC2 instances. You can spin up as many as you can afford, and you can use multiple instances at the same time to try things out in parallel.

Good luck.

---

Comment: haha I'm a high school student so that isn't an option :)

Comment: You might have some success getting a teacher there to apply, the page here specifically calls out high schools as qualifying for resources on AWS - it's good marketing to hook you on their services early anyway :)  https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/